# Opera: How do I hide scroll bar? (not there in Firefox and IE8)

Tags: css, scrollbar, opera, hidden

I'm testing my pages in different browsers.

Opera puts a vertical scroll bar on a page. I added an overflow:hidden to the div (after trying Opera), but the scroll bar is still there. How do I get rid of it (you don't need the scroll bar to view the page).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following

```
html, body { 
  overflow: auto;
}
```

`overflow: hidden` will make the scrollbars disappear even if the window is resized.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that would get rid of the scrollbar on the window in the middle of the page, too - but it's still there. Thanks.

Comment: try setting `overflow-x: hidden`

Answer (score 0):

To turn off the default scroll bar go in Settings → Preferences → Advanced → Browsing, deactivate “Show scrollbars”.

Comment: he is talking about hidding them when the content is too big, so the answer goes for the use of overflow

Answer (score -2):

sadly though, you can't get rid of 1 of the scroll bars. You must have both in a Mac Opera 9.20 .... IMO Opera is garbage, dont use it and dont design for it.

Comment: This kind of 'don't design for it' kind of reinforces the use of the problematic vendor prefixes instead of proper W3C conventions.

If they are a problem, post an error report to mozilla to ask them to change it. If you have a use faq on your site, include the instructions for how to set things up for different browsers. Not supporting what potential customers will use is not the best answer.